# iphone development: caching images with asyncimageview library

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, caching, uiimageview

In my app I use AsyncImageView library to load and display images asynchronously and it also claims that it caches the images.

The library can be found here : https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView

Well, I have a tableview and it has imageviews inside its rows. Thanks to the asyncimageview library I can successfully lazy load the images so there is no problem. But I have questions about the caching property of that library.

What I expect from cache, for example I push to a view controller which has my tableview for the first time, it lazy loads the images with that library. However, when I go back from that view and go push again, if noting is changed, I think it should retrieve the images from the cache. Not necessary to download the images again. But in this library it downloads the images again. Do I need to do something extra to do it? or it is not possible to have that kind of caching property at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used this library once. It caches all images into memory, and for me it worked quite well.

> Loaded/downloaded images are cached in memory and are automatically
>   cleaned up in the event of a memory warning

So it should persist cached images after go back and forth in navigation hierarchy unless your app receives a memory warning. If you feel like library does not perform as described, you may submit an bug report / issue to the developer.

Comment: for example what I did is I opened the viewcontroller with the tableview and loaded the images. then I go back and disconnect from the internet. After that I push again to that viewcontroller but noting can be seen. If it is cached, it should be seen right?

Comment: yes, you are right, if it is cached, it should be seen even without network connection. Are your sure you are not loading very large images that are causing memory warnings and clearing the cache?

Comment: well, you may implement -(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning in your UIViewController, or - (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application in your UIApplicationDelegate. This methods will get called when you receive memory warning.

Comment: At first I want to say thank you very much for your kind attention:) I do not receive any memory warning. In addition, my images are not large at all.

Answer (score -1):

I've solved this problem: you need to add

```
#import "AsyncImageView.h"
```

in your file .m

and USE

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:yourUrlString];
photo.imageURL = url;
```

OR FOR EXAMPLE

```
cell.imageView.imageURL = url;
```

and NOT

```
UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
photo.image = theImage;
```